# Is the map $\ g:S \otimes_R A \to T \otimes_R A \ $ also faithfully flat?

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R, S, T$ are commutative rings with $R \subset S \subset T$ and  $f:S \to T$ is faithfully flat.

Assume $A$ be a finite flat $R$-algebra. $$ \text{Is the map $\ g:S \otimes_R A \to  T \otimes_R A \ $ also faithfully flat ?}$$
If $R \to S$ is also faithfully flat, case then in that  case, I think the above map $g$ will be faithfully flat.

Does the result follows without assuming $R \to S$ faithfully flat?

Any help  please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u: M \rightarrow N$ be a morphism of $S \otimes_R A$-modules. Then $M \otimes_{S \otimes_R A} (T \otimes_R A) \cong M \otimes_S T$ with the $A$-algebra structure on $M$ directly (same for $N$); and $u'=u \otimes_{S \otimes_R A} (T \otimes_R A)$ acts under these isomorphisms as $u \otimes_S T: M \otimes_S T \rightarrow N \otimes_S T$. So $u$ is injective iff $u \otimes_S T$ is injective, iff $u'$ is injective.

So $S \otimes_R A \rightarrow T \otimes_R A$ is faithfully flat.

More directly, you can check that $T \otimes_R A = T \otimes_S (S \otimes_R A)$ so your map is a "base change" of the faithfully flat map $S \rightarrow T$.

Comment: So I see finiteness of $A$ is not necessary

Comment: No information at all about $A$ is necessary, actually. Just that $S \rightarrow T$ be faithfully flat.

Comment: Thanks. But the flatness is not clear to me. We have shown the map is faithful so far. Now we have to show $T \otimes_R A$ is flat $(S \otimes_R A)$-module. Now we have $T$ is $S$-flat module and $A$ is $R$-flat module. Does this mean their tensor product $(T \otimes_RA)$ is flat $(S \otimes_R A)$-module ?

Comment: I showed the flatness and the faithfulness by showing that $u$ was injective if and only $u’$ was injective.

Comment: Oh, yes I got it. It was silly misunderstanding, I did look at the definition.  Anyway, lot of thanks